# jQuery unordered list slide menu

Tags: jquery, html-lists, slidetoggle

I am trying to mimic a dependent select list using unordered lists and jQuery so i can style my lists how I want because I can't style select lists.

The problem i'm having is if the second menu is open and i click on the first menu, i need the second menu to close before opening the first.

This is the bit i think is cusing the problem.

```
if($("#next_menu").is(':visible')) {
    $("#next_menu").slideToggle(200);
}
```

Also, is there a way i can improve the code to make it more efficient like chaining events?  I've seen people do code in only a couple of lines and don't know if this is possible with what i've got.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide the menu on page load
    $('#current_menu').hide();
    // hide each of the linked menus on page load
    $('#next_menu > ul').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#current_page").click(function() {

        if($("#next_menu").is(':visible')) {
            $("#next_menu").slideToggle(200);
        }
        // slide up/down the first menu
        $("#current_menu").slideToggle(200);
    });

    $("#current_menu li").click(function(event) {
        // set the text of div to what was clicked
        $("#current_page").html($(this).text());

        // get the id if the clicked <li>
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        //slide up the first menu
        $("#current_menu").slideToggle(200, function() {

            $("ul." + id).show();
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="aaa">
    <div id="current_page">Default Value</div>
    <div id="current_menu">
      <ul>
        <li id="a"><a href="#">Option A</a></li>
        <li id="b"><a href="#">Option B</a></li>
        <li id="c"><a href="#">Option C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aaa">
    <div id="next_page">Default Value</div>
    <div id="next_menu">
        <ul class="a">
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
        <ul></ul>
        <ul class="b">
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="c">
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
            <li>Lipsum</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add same class in the menus like .menus

```
$('.menus').click(function(){
  if(!$(this).is(':visible'){
   $('.menus').hide();
   $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't understand what you mean. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You have two menus. Add same class example '.menus' to the each menu. Then if you click one of them the script first check if clicked menu is visible if not it will hide all menus and then clicked one will be visible :)